# Which flag reason should I use when flagging comments?

Tags: support, comments, flagging

When I'm flagging a comment, which flag reason should I use?

Comment: We've been getting a ton of comment flags lately that use the wrong flag reason, ergo this PSA.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/158781):

> ### When should I flag a comment?
>
> [image: image of flag dialog]
>
> You must specify a [reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93821/what-are-valid-reasons-for-flagging-comments) for each comment flag. The dialog offers a few pre-filled reasons that cover most common cases:
>
> - It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.
>
>   The comment attacks a person or group.
>
> - It's unfriendly or unkind.
>
>   The comment is rude or condescending.
>
> - It's no longer needed.
>
>   This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to the post.
>
> - Something else.
>
>   A problem not listed above. Try to be as specific as possible.
>
> See also [When should comments be deleted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/when-should-comments-be-deleted/2235#2235).